# Create XML based on XSD from data in DB

Tags: java, xml, xsd

this is first time I work with XML so maybe it is very easy problem, but I would like to ask what is the best way I should create XML filled with data from DB when I know the schema.

Of course there is possibility to do it manually, but I would like to do something like this:

create configuration file which would specify **column name**, **xpath**, **default value** (if DB column is not populated) and based on this configuration file to create XML based on known schema.

Is there some tool in java which would allow be something like this?

```
MagicXMLTool tool = new MagicXMLTool(mySchema.xsd);
tool.set("some/xpath/",value);
tool.set("another/xpath",anotherValue)
String xml = tool.generateXML();
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use XSD to generate Java classes, map SQL result to those classes, send classes, xml marshalling is done by Jaxb or whatever framework you choose to use.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, what you offer is of course possibility (and I will go that way probably), but if I would need to change the location of some value from DB in xml I would need to change the java code. But when what I suggest would be possible I would just edit the config file.

Comment: You have an xsd so that would change as well as the structure. So not sure how that would work. Instead of trying to build something that you probably aren't going to need (aka over-engineering) what about just writing a solution? It is probably easier to change 1 line of java code then to write a mapping framework and prove it is correct. Just my 2ct.

Comment: It is also quite complicated when I have xpath long like this x1/x2/x3/x4/x5/x6/x7/x8, I have to create a lot of new classes to set the parameter, but maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You can just generate those classes from the XSD

Comment: Yes, I have generated the classes but to set x8 I have to do something like X1 x1 = new X1().setX2(new X2().setX3(new X3()))...

Comment: That needs to be done anyway? Either through what you do or through the framework you are going to use/build. You could also ditch all the XML, use a templating library like Freemarker or Thymeleaf and create an XML template, fill a model (generally a hashmap) and generate XML. It would work, not sure if that is best way.

Comment: Ok, I found this: https://github.com/mklemm/jaxb2-rich-contract-plugin which makes it more usable.